# Minification with Directives and anonymous AngularJS controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the '**ng-strict-di**' directive in my application to protect against failing minification. But now I am getting an error on my directives.

*Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($scope, element, attrs) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode*

How do I explicitly add $scope as a dependency to the anonymous controller function? Here is my directive.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<h4> {{myController.msg}} </h4>',
    controller: function($scope, element, attrs){
      $scope.myController = this;
      this.msg = "Hello world";
    };
});
```

I tried:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp ', ['$scope'])
```

But I get this error:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need minification safe syntax for the directive controller:

```
controller: ["$scope", "element", "attrs", function($scope, element, attrs){
  $scope.myController = this;
  this.msg = "Hello world";
}];
```

Based on those params tho, I'm guessing you wanted a `link` function (just a guess):

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs){
  $scope.myController = this;
  this.msg = "Hello world";
};
```

Comment: The first part is ok. The choice of `link` should be a bit more valid than just its arguments. Also, `this` is undefined in `link` (irrespective of the fact that `$scope.myController = this;` is a use case for controllerAs and shouldn't be there at all).

Comment: Thanks! I think all need is controller: ["$scope", function ($scope, element, attrs)

Comment: @estus -- Yeah, it was an assumption based on the params passed into the controller func